# How Exporting a table to Excel?

Tags: angularjs, excel, model-view-controller, export, html-table

what is the best way of this? I have table and it's data coming from api. I used angularJs for data. Here my source codes:

Here's my table in Index:

```
<div style="width:1100px; max-height:480px; overflow:scroll; border-top:1px solid #808080">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>AdaNo</th>
                        <th>ParselNo</th>
                        <th>CiltNo</th>
                        <th>SayfaNo</th>
                        <th>ZeminTip</th>
                        <th>İl</th>
                        <th>İlçe</th>
                        <th>Mahalle</th>
                        <th>Kurum</th>
                        <th>Alan</th>
                        <th>Pay</th>
                        <th>Nitelik</th>
                        <th>EdinmeSebep</th>
                        <th>Ad</th>
                        <th>SoyAd</th>
                        <th>TcKimlikNo</th>
                        <th>HissePay</th>
                        <th>HissePayda</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="zemin in Zeminler">
                        <td>{{zemin.AdaNo}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.ParselNo}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.CiltNo}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.SayfaNo}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.ZeminTip.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Il.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Ilce.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Mahalle.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Kurum.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.AnaTasinmaz.Alan}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.KatMulkiyeti.ArsaPay}}/{{zemin.KatMulkiyeti.ArsaPayda}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.AnaTasinmaz.Nitelik}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].EdinmeSebep}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].Kisi.GercekKisi.Ad}}{{zemin.Hisseler[0].Kisi.TuzelKisi.Ad}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].Kisi.GercekKisi.SoyAd}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].Kisi.GercekKisi.TcKimlikNo}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].HissePay}}</td>
                        <td>{{zemin.Hisseler[0].HissePayda}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Here's my Apis for this Data:

```
 [Route("api/TapuZeminApi/GetZemins")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetZeminsFromZeminArg(object arg)
    {
        ZeminArg zemArg = SConvert.DeserializeJSON<ZeminArg>(arg.ToString());

        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromArgs(zemArg);
       
        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string GetZeminsFromTcNo(long id)
    {
        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromTcNo(id.ToString());

        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }

    public string GetZeminsFromKurumId(long id)
    {
        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListKurumId(id);

        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

[Article](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4)

I used it in my solution like:

First made ExportToExcelService.Js:

```
angular.module('TapuAppModule')
.factory('Excel', function tapuExcelFactory($window) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) { return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); },
        format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };
    return {
        tableToExcel: function (tableId, worksheetName) {
            alert('Olcak olcak')
            var table = $(tableId),
                ctx = { worksheet: worksheetName, table: table.html() },
                href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
})
```

and here my controller tapuController.js:

```
$scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) {
        $scope.exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'sheet name');
        $timeout(function () { location.href = $scope.fileData.exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
    };
```

and my button like this in Index:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#dataTable')">
                <span class="w-icon-page-excel"></span> Export to Excel
            </button>
```

When I click button I'm getting alert that in ExportToExcelService.Js 'Olcak Olcak'. So I think it can be triggered method in ExportToExcelService.Js. Then I got this error like at console in Chrome:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'exportHref' of undefined
> at tapuController.js:81
> at angular.js:17682
> at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5387)
> at angular.js:5659

Why I'm getting this error? What should I do?

Comment: You can generate csv file from Zeminler array http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

Comment: Confused about what? Need to be more specific per the research you've done

Comment: AngularUI-Grid makes displaying and exporting the data quick and easy.

Comment: I found something in this article
https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4
i use that but i'm getting an error like when i checked console in Chrome:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exportHref' of undefined
    at tapuController.js:81
    at angular.js:17682
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5387)
    at angular.js:5659

Comment: i edited my question with last my source and my last error.

Comment: If you are looking to export your HTML table data into Excel.. you could use this http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Comment: Ty my friend but for now need with use with Html Table. So have any idea for my error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the location.href value by $scope.exportHref; without fileData.

```
$timeout(function () { location.href = $scope.exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
```

that works for me.